# Can I use something like += in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I tried to search for this in google, but the `+=` part is ignored.

So I want to add some text to a variable:

```
Text := 'asdf';
Text := Text + 'ghijk';
```

This works fine, but for longer variable names, something like this would be nice:

```
Text := 'asdf';
Text += 'ghijk';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try using quotation marks in google. 
They are for literal search.

Comment: I did, still got pictures from the ancient Greek city.

Comment: In the "Picture Results" section i guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such operator available in the language.

For ordinal types you can use `inc` and `dec` but for all other types there is nothing.

For strings you can use [`TStringBuilder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder) to append to a text buffer. Although you may well conclude that, in many cases, is more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: Lazarus/FPC supports this notation.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi does not support compound operators like C++ does.  However, in XE3 and later, you can write a [record helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) for native data types, like `String` (see [`SysUtils.TStringHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper) for an example).  So you can write a helper that adds a custom `Append()` method to the `String` type, then you can use `Text.Append('ghijk')` in your code.

Comment: A mutating helper method for string is probably not ideal. Plus any helper for string removes the built in helper and is thus probably crippling.

Comment: Also record helpers are an xe3 addition

Comment: Class/record helpers are unit-specific, so you could use the standard helper in one unit and a custom helper in another unit.

Comment: are you really suggesting that a new string helper is a sound idea here? It's fine to say that it can be done but in my view it is wrong to bless this as a good solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Whats funny that Embarcadero isn't ready to fix this.. rather the single helper per string is a "feature"..

Comment: It is an available option. If you don't like it, you don't have to use it, but don't tell other people not to use it if it solves their problem. Embarcadero went to the trouble of implementing helpers, so why not use them? And FYI, class helpers DO support inheritance (even virtual methods) so you could derive a class helper from another helper if you don't want to lose its functionality when defining a new helper. I have to check if the same applies to record helpers. The syntax for inheritance exists.

Comment: @remy no need to FYI me. Try using inheritance on a record helper.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Don't tell me what to use when Delphi XE5 has a price of over 3 grand. Yet a free FPC happens to support inheritance for record helpers and more!

Comment: @user Put helpers next to .net extension methods and it's a sorry sight. Non-inheritance based extension is massively powerful but implemented in a lame fashion in Delphi.

Comment: *Embarcadero went to the trouble of implementing helpers, so why not use them?* I do use them. I'm very happy using `TStringHelper` and many other helpers. I happily implement my own helpers where useful. But adding a helper that wipes out `TStringHelper` is not good practice. Also, I'm also very surprised that you recommend mutating helper methods. I would not do so. Anyway, at the very least it is remiss of you to omit mention that implementing a helper for `string` will wipe out `TStringHelper`. Perhaps you did not do so because you did not know that record helpers cannot be inherited.

Comment: @user helper inheritance isn't really the issue here. It is also a bad solution to the problem. The goal is to allow multiple helpers to be in effect. Inheritance is a poor way to achieve that. Look how it is done with C# extension methods.

Comment: IMO, the shipped helpers should have been built-in to the compiler when there is such restriction...

Comment: @TLama I think they are working towards that. The built in helpers are a stepping stone. The goal is to have a rooted type system: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2013/06/14/38948